# How to get a image as a background of a section

Tags: html, css

Trying to get an image to be the background of a section of code. Have tried inline html attribute style and css styles but neither has worked. Even tried giving it precedence with !important, but with the same result. The selector is definitely targeting the element so what is causing the issue and how would one go about fixing it?

```css
#intro {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("image.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section id="intro">
  <div class="intro-text">
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Do the elements nested within `#intro` have their own backgrounds set, which would sit 'on top of' the background of the `#intro` element? Does `image.jpg` correctly identify the image you wish to use (the path, in the CSS stylesheet, should be relative to the CSS file not the HTML file)? Note that, in JS Fiddle (with an appropriate alternative image specified) it works perfectly: https://jsfiddle.net/rswp772r/

Comment: Yes the image is targeted correctly and the the only thing on top of the intro section are some text in the <h2> and <p> tags. As well as 3 pics which are in the "product" div. They all work just fine. The original styling I was using was a linear gradient which worked fine, but decided to switch to an img. Tried messing with the margins but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

It works with a real image - see below. The only thing to note: The white space above the image is due to the default margin of the `h2`, which extends above the section ("collapsing margins"). If you want to avoid that, add

```
#intro h2:first--of-type { 
  margin-top: 0; 
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#intro {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/500x350/fa0");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section id="intro">
  <div class="intro-text">
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I get what your trying to do, and have tried it. However it still does not seem to work for some reason

Comment: When you write "it still does not seem to work...", that's nothing I can really react to, since it doesn't describe WHAT doesn't work or what your result looks like... A detailed description would be necessary to be able to help you

Comment: my apologies. I meant that the picture is still not being displayed as the background, as is my my main objective.

Comment: well, then the reason has to be the file path to the image file, I suppose.

Comment: See I thought that too but all my pics are in the same folder and my project can grab all the other ones just fine. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: If your CSS is in an external stylesheet, the background-image path has to be relative to the stylesheet file, not to the HTML file...